# How can I validate DataGridView input?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, data-binding, datagridview

I have some serious problem with *DataGridView* input validation:

I'm working on a project with Entity Framework and I've bound a *DataGridView* element to a database.

If the user inserts some data into a non-nullable column, and after that clears the data to leave the column blank, then clicks on another *DataGridView* cell, an exception occurs and I get a run-time error.

Alternately, if a user tries to insert a string into an integer column, they get a very long error message which isn't user friendly at all.

Is it any easy way to validate *DataGridView* cells?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for `DataGridView.DataError` event. you should handle this event if you want to have custom validation on data. something like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = entities;
        dataGridView1.DataError += new DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(dataGridView1_DataError);
    }

    void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        // you can obtain current editing value like this:
        string value = null;
        var ctl = dataGridView1.EditingControl as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;

        if (ctl != null)
            value = ctl.Text;

        // you can obtain the current commited value
        object current = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        string message;
        switch (e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                // bound to integer field
                message = "the value should be a number";
                break;
            case 1:
                // bound to date time field
                message = "the value should be in date time format yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss";
                break;
            // other columns
            default:
                message = "Invalid data";
                break;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
```

you can check the value of entered data and show appropriate error message for that value. for example if value is null or empty and the field is not nullable, you can show a message indicating that the value cannot be empty.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it dont work when you bound `DataGridView` to `Entity FrameWork`

Comment: @masoudkeshavarz I've tested with entity framework 4.0, it works for me. I think your situation is different, can you explain exactly what you are doing, like how do you provide the data source for gridview, which column type do you change at runtime that doesn't enter `DataError` event.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Ive tried to handle this exception with `DataError` before. But when you work with `Entity FrameWork` `DataError` event never occur. When you leave a field with null value an exception occur from somewhere else with following message: "This property cannot be set to a null value". I provided `Data Source` with following steps. I made an `edmx` file. I dragged my tables into it. I clicked on `Add New Data Source` in `Data Source` tab and I choose d data provide from `Object`. Then I bound my `DataGridView` to it.

Comment: Why not then map the EF classes into DTOs or ViewModels? Then you bind to simple objects, validate as soon or as late as you want, and get database/domain/whatever specific error when you map them back. And as a bonus, decouples the view from the datastore, leaving you free to do refactoring if it ever becomes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code for handling the [`DataError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror.aspx) event:

```
switch (e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                // bound to integer field
                message = "the value should be a number";
                break;
            case 1:
                // bound to date time field
                message = "the value should be in date time format yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss";
                break;
            // other columns
            default:
                message = "Invalid data";
                break;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(message);
```